# md_update_sb keeping boot RAID 1 busy

Tags: boot, raid, mdadm

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS on 4 hard drives in a RAID 1 configuration. Something is keeping the hard drives busy and they never spin down. Things I did: 
- mapped frequently accessed directories (/var/log, /tmp etc) as tmpfs into memory
- locked /bin, /sbin and several libraries via vmtouch into memory

After those changes, iotop shows only kworker accessing the array.

btrace shows this:

```
9,0    0        0   350.464025971     0  m   N md md_update_sb
9,0    0       98   350.849029580  2206  Q  WM 71305144 + 8 [kworker/u128:0]
9,0    0       99   350.849034110  2206  Q  WM 71305216 + 8 [kworker/u128:0]
9,0    0      100   350.849038452  2206  Q  WM 71371648 + 8 [kworker/u128:0]
9,0    0      101   350.849045694  2206  Q   W 0 + 8 [kworker/u128:0]
9,0    0      102   350.849048534  2206  Q  WM 40 + 8 [kworker/u128:0]
9,0    1      137   350.976982774     0  C   W 0 + 8 [0]
9,0    1      138   350.994303913     0  C  WM 40 + 8 [0]
9,0    1      139   350.997638530     0  C  WM 71303296 + 8 [0]
9,0    1      140   351.011237159   353  C  WM 71305144 + 8 [0]
9,0    1      141   351.011403025     0  C  WM 71305216 + 8 [0]
9,0    1      142   351.276814094   353  C  WM 71371648 + 8 [0]
9,0    0        0   351.599976239     0  m   N md md_update_sb
```

If I understand the trace correctly, something is updating the array's superblock? What else can I do to trace down what's keeping disks awake?

**Update 1**: A RAID 6 is also set up on the same disks but it is not mounted and there doesn't seem to be any access to it.

`cat /proc/mdstat`

```
Personalities : [linear] [multipath] [raid0] [raid1] [raid6] [raid5] [raid4] [raid10] 
md127 : active raid6 sde3[5] sdd3[4] sdc3[1] sdb3[0]
      10737154048 blocks super 1.2 level 6, 512k chunk, algorithm 2 [4/4] [UUUU]
      bitmap: 0/40 pages [0KB], 65536KB chunk

md0 : active raid1 sde2[5] sdd2[4] sdc2[2] sdb2[6]
      52395008 blocks super 1.2 [4/4] [UUUU]

unused devices: <none>
```

**Update 2:** `inotifywait -r -m /` traces all access to the file system. Progressively filtering out everything that is mounted into memory already...

`inotifywait -r -m / @/dev @/sys @/proc @/run @/var/tmp @/tmp @/var/log @/var/spool`

... showed snapd writing files. As I'm not aware of anything that needs snapd in my installation, I purged it.

Comment: Please add the output of `cat /proc/mdstat` to your question here as that might show if drive sync or updates is going on.

Comment: Thanks Terrance; updated.

Comment: Hmmm, I am not seeing anything out of the ordinary.  Maybe try mounting options as shown in https://forums.gentoo.org/viewtopic-t-843292.html  I have a RAID 5 and RAID 1 at home, but I am not seeing anything on mine close to that message, so I might not be much more help from here.

Answer (score 0):

Anyhow, following inotifywait logs I found one by one the processes (there were many!) writing to the file system. I remapped each directory to a tmpfs with a boot script, copying files to the tmpfs and remounting it instead of the file system location and then copying files back at shutdown. This has caveats, but it'll do for now.